# PYTHON nuevo diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.7

Me pueden ayudar.

Tengo un diccionario y una lista:

```
dicc={"pesos_uruguayo":[20, 10, 15, 20]}
globo= [25]
```

Lo que quiero es que se multiplique el dicc y el globo y que el resultado se guarde en una nuevo diccionario.
Alguien sabe cómo se hace? Pueden hacerlo por medio de loop for o while.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: `nuevo_dict = {k:[x*globo[0] for x in v] for k,v in dicc.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

La forma de modificar el diccionario a través de un bucle es esta:

```
dicc = {"pesos_uruguayo": [20, 10, 15, 20]}

# Modifico esta parte ya que esto estaba como una lista (globo = [25]) y no es necesario
globo = 25

# Creo una variable donde almaceno los datos del diccionario
valores_diccionario = list(dicc.get("pesos_uruguayo"))

nuevos_valores: list = []

for valores in valores_diccionario:
    # Creo una nueva lista con lo valores multiplicados
    nuevos_valores += [valores * globo]

# Creo el nuevo diccionario
nuevo_diccionario = {"pesos_uruguayo": nuevos_valores}
```

Este problema también lo puedes solucionar a través de una comprensión de diccionario como han mencionado en los comentarios del post pero, si acabas de empezar, por experiencia propia puede ser un poco difícil de entender ese método.

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda